# How to delay between animation and appear after previous animation in css

Tags: css, animation, delay

I want to ask, how to make the delay between animation in css? I've tried to make it but it still appears at the beginning and then the animation function.

What I want is the object / text only show after the previous animation (object 3).

Here is my code in jsfiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/sugoi/bV6Pc/]

Thank you

Comment: jquery? [jquery delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with the opacity.
Let see : [fork jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmF8G/)

```
.slideRight {
    opacity: 0.0;
}

@keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-150%);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    <!--...-->
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

But it seems to need some js..

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But, why after it the animation is disappear? How to make it always show at the end? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Within the css animation, you can specify a delay, so you can manipulate the two animations 
syntax - animation: name duration timing-function delay iteration-count direction;